# Sproutcore server proxy problem on ubuntu

Tags: sproutcore

I have setup a proxy in the build file which was working perfectly on 
my mac at work. But on my Ubuntu 11.04 laptop at home the proxy seems 
to never return a valid response (checking with SC.ok(response)).

I have checked by curling the url:

curl -G http://localhost:4020/api/client

**Output:**

[{"id":"1","title":"Test","status":"1","created":"2011-07-03 07:36:44","updated":"2011-07-03 07:36:44","brands":null}, 
{"id":"2","title":"Arla","status":"1","created":"2011-07-03 07:43:53","updated":"2011-07-03 07:43:53","brands":null}]

Anyone got any ideas? 
Thanks 
Mark

Comment: Can you post your proxy configuration? Is the output the expected output as returned on your mac at work?

Comment: proxy '/api', :to => 'local.dbs.net' - Proxy config - and yes its the same as at work.

Comment: Stranger still, I have just tried Midori (a webkit based browser) and it looks like that is receiving JSON. But looks like its getting truncated.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is due to the fact that at work the REST server is running off a different computer and at work its working off my local computer. I have a modified hosts file to point to the proper ips.

Comment: That sounds very likely. I don't have a better explanation and would guess, that the either the name resolution doesn't work properly or that there's a firewall of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/issues/584) similar to this one. It seems that the Thin web server can't handle gzipped content from an upstream server.
If you can disable gzip on the remote server and please upvote the issue on github so that it has better chances of getting fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Apache at home check Your log files (while running the app):

```
tail -20f  /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

You might get this error:

```
Client sent malformed Host header
```

This is because the Host header (more precise the port) is different than Apaches standard localhost:80.